# Django based marketplace, creating a transaction history

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a transaction history for each transaction on a Django based marketplace.

I thought the best way of keeping track of this data was to override the save() function and create a Transaction record.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True)
    buyer = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='buyer')
    seller = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='seller')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    purchase_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.buyer.money+=self.value
        self.seller.money-=self.value
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Am I going about this all wrong? Currenlty I get...

```
'Transaction' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to save your object *before* you can go through many-to-many relationships.
2. Please explain how you can have multiple buyers and sellers on a single transaction.  (For the rest of this answer, I'm assuming that there aren't and you meant for these to be `ForeignKey` fields.)
3. The related names for buyer and seller are not clear.  See below.
4. I'm not sure what `description` is for.  Is it different from the item list?
5. `item` should be called `items`, since it can be plural, and you might want to create a custom junction table (using the "through" parameter) with a quantity field.
6. You forgot to save the related objects.

Modified version:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='TransactionItem', blank=True)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='transactions_as_buyer')
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='transactions_as_seller')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    purchase_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.buyer.money += self.value
        self.buyer.save()
        self.seller.money -= self.value
        self.seller.save()

class TransactionItem(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Not only was this a great answer.. We may be relatives.

Answer (score 1):

The `buyer` and `seller` fields are many to many fields so `self.buyer` will never work, I think you were meaning to use `ForeignKey` instead of `ManyToManyField`.